# Assign an SSL certificate to an Azure App Service

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-web-app-service

I have purchased an SSL certificate for my domain and have jumped through all domain verification hoops.  My App Service Plan is B1 (I also tried S1).

I am following the instructions here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-purchase-ssl-web-site#step-5---assign-certificate-to-app-service-app

When I click SSL Settings, the pane that opens looks nothing like what is shown in the instructions, and there is no option to import a certificate. Note also the instructions say "click SSL settings" but the image in the instructions shows "SSL Certificates" which does not exist in my image.

What steps do I need to take to assign my SSL cert?

[image]

Comment: If you are not getting the options, try refreshing the page or logout and re-login then check.

Comment: Refreshing my session did the trick.

Comment: Good to hear that your issue is resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the correct place, if you go down a bit, you should see those options, if not try refreshing the page

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately the image I posted was the whole blade. After refreshing my session I was able to see the options.

Comment: great, hope this answer would help others

Answer (score 0):

Per Ashok's comment, the session had to be refreshed and the options I'm looking for appeared.